# ClickHouse source code: where is IBlockInputStream interface?

Tags: clickhouse

At the end of 2021, the DataStreams folder was removed from the ClickHouse source code update. What has replaced streams such as BlockInputStream、BlockOutputStream? Thank you!

I wonder what new things are being used to replace Block Stream. Where is it in the source code? I'm new to C++ and databases， recently read the source code for ClickHouse.